# How to show customised error page for forbidden url access in grails 3.3.9

Tags: grails, spring-security, grails-plugin, grails-3.3

My grails `3.3.9` application has different modules implemented with different `ROLE` based access using spring security.

AdminController accessed via `ROLE_ADMIN`.
If a non-admin user logged in and try to access `Admin URL` then grails show

`[Image]`[Grails Error Message: `Sorry, you're not authorized to view this page.`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gkGaA.png)

I want to show my custom message.

`[Image: ]`[Custom Message: `403 Access Forbidden`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bZXFG.png)

> application.groovy

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.interceptUrlMap = [
        [pattern: '/user/**', access: ['IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY']],
        [pattern: '/role/**', access: ['ROLE_ADMIN']],
        [pattern: '/', access: ['IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY']],
        [pattern: '/admin/*', access: ['ROLE_ADMIN']]]
```

> URLMappings

```
"500"(controller: "error", action: "internalServerError")
"404"(controller: "error", action: "notFound")
"403" (controller: "error", action: "forbidden")
"403"(view: "/error/forbidden")
```

I have individually for `403`.

`500 & 404` is working correctly.

Answer (score 2):

In URlMappings you can set a mapping to the response code and choose a controller or view to respond with - eg:

```
static mappings = {
    // ... other mappings ...
    // Send 403's to a controller if you'd like to do additional logic
    "403"(controller: "errors", action: "forbidden")
    // Or just render a static view under grails-app/views/errors/forbidden.gsp
    "403"(view: "/errors/forbidden")
}
```

See: http://docs.grails.org/4.0.1/guide/single.html#mappingToResponseCodes

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention the URLMapping. I have defined the action for 403 but still, it is not working. You can see above

Comment: Do you have 2 definitions for 403? Try with just the view OR the controller.

Comment: I had tried either way. I just have mentioned it at once

Answer (score 0):

You need to set following configuration in application.groovy as well.

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.adh.errorPage = null //to throw 403 page on access denied
```